# Modify Wordpress paiging URL name as other language installation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/Woocommerce installation with Swedish base language and have a trouble with mixing language in the URL.

All title and pages is in Swedish but when I have a category with several pages of product the link of the page number shows with English word "page" instead of Swedish word "sida".

https://mydomain/categori/page/2/
Instead
https://mydomain/categori/sida/2/

i tried with this code to fix it:

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base    = 'sida';
    if ( ! get_option('my_re_rewrite_rules_flushed', false) ) {
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        update_option( 'my_re_rewrite_rules_flushed', time());
    }
    
}
add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
```

The above code fix the problem for all categories without the shop page. My shop page's URL is:

https://mydomain/butik/

and when click on anothe page number the URL become like:

https://mydomain/butik/sida/2

I got an empty page without any product. (all element in the page is remains just doesn't shows any product)

What I need to modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce registers its own rewrite rules, which might override your custom rules. You need to ensure that your rewrite rules are compatible with WooCommerce's.

Here is the example you should try:

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'sida';
}

function flush_rewrite_rules_once() {
    if (!get_option('my_re_rewrite_rules_flushed', false)) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        update_option('my_re_rewrite_rules_flushed', time());
    }
}

function custom_woocommerce_shop_pagination_base() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^butik/sida/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=product&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
add_action('wp_loaded', 'flush_rewrite_rules_once');
add_action('init', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_pagination_base');
```